# Why two lambs to make a meal for Isaac?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, number, food, animals, parashat-toldot

In parshat Toldot Rivka asks Yaakov to get 2 kids for her to cook for Isaac. What can we learn from using two kids? Was it in the time of year when kids are first born and they were tiny?  Was a certain delicacy made from a small part of the animal? Was Isaac a big eater?

Answer (score 6):

Kitzur Baal Haturim on Genesis 27:9:1:

> **לך נא אל הצאן** ר''ת נאה לך. פירוש נאה לך ונאה לבניך כי פסח היה
>   ולקח ב' אחד לפסח וא' לחגיגה:

Synopsis - it ws Pesach. One lamb for the Pesach sacrifice and another reresenting the *chagigah* - holiday sacrifice.

Re was Yitzchak a boig eater? - I assume you are asking this because it looks like two goats is a huge amount of food to prepare for one person. Explanation:

Haamek Davar on Genesis 27:9:2:

**שני גדיי עזים טובים.** אע״ג שהוא מרובה יותר ממאכל אדם. לפי הפשט הוא בשביל שני העורות על ידיו :

My translation (loose):

It is more than what one person can eat. Part of it was used to make the skins that covered part of Ya'akov's hands (to make it seem that he was hairy like Esav.)

Comment: Did Pesach preceed the exodus?  How does that make sense?

Comment: @YehudaW Keep in mind that not everything in Midrash can be taken 100% literally. One of the most common general principal mentioned is that the forefathers observed all the Torah mitzvot. How can they do EVERYTHING, esp. when many of them apply to events that haevn't yet occurred?